# How to manage two user roles in flutter?

Tags: django, flutter, firebase-authentication, state-management, system-design

I am building an MVP for a two-user type flutter mobile app,(eg: Like a delivery app with a driver and a rider).

Since is an MVP is it efficient to keep both user types in one application and switch app states depending on the type of the user and their role?

Comment: Yes.  Dunno "efficient", but at least doable.

Comment: Oh okay, Thank you. I wanted try to build an MVP with a minimal or less amount of code as fast as I can.